# packaging qtwebkit for windows

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm developing a qtwebkit based editor on linux using pyqt.  I would like to package it for windows too.  Is it possible?  what is the procedure for that?  I could not find any googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found pyinstaller works like a charm for all windows, linux and mac

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

[Deploy PyQt Applications on Mac OS X with PyInstaller](http://tech.xster.net/tips/deploy-pyqt-applications-on-mac-os-x-with-pyinstaller/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend py2exe, i'm using it for an application of mine and there's even a wiki concerning PyQt

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt